# Uploading files and preventing duplicates by knowing to update the file

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, valums-file-uploader

In our system, when a user uploads a file it is stored in a unique file system structure and a database record is generated. A file is uploaded via the webbrowser via XMLHttpRequest. The file then gets moved from the temporary upload area into the FS.

**How can I detect that a file after being uploaded already exists in my FS?**

```
If the file uploaded is the same as one already uploaded.
If the file is the same file, but the uploaded content has been updated which 
  means I need to update the file in the FS.
```

I am ignoring file names as a way of knowing if the file already exists. A filename cannot be considered unique. An example is that some cameras name photos using an incremental number that rolls over after a time. 
When a file is uploaded via the web browser, the source file structure is masked. E.g. `C:\Users\Drive\File\Uploaded\From`. So I cant use the that to figure out if the file has already been uploaded.

How do I know the file being uploaded already exists because its content is the same. Or it exists but because the uploaded file has been changed, so I can just update the file?

Microsoft Word documents create a challenge as Word regenerates the file on every save.

In a situation where the user renames a file on their own accord, I could say tough luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with finding files that are the same via an SHA Hash. You could use something like this to get a list of files that have the same hash as your newly uploaded file then take some action.

Just an example of getting the hash of the new file:

```
string newfile;
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(   string newfile;
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Drive\\File\\Uploaded\\From\\newfile.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed sha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed())
        {
            newfile = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(fs));
        }
    }
```

This goes through all files and gets a list of file names and hashes

```
var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Drive\File\Uploaded\From\", "*.*")
        .Select(
            f => new
                     {
                         FileName = f,
                         FileHash = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed()
                                                            .ComputeHash(new FileStream(f, 
                                                                             FileMode.Open, 
                                                                             FileAccess.Read))
                     })       
        .ToList();

        foreach(var fi in allfiles){
        if(newfile == BitConverter.ToString(fi.FileHash))
            Console.WriteLine("Match!!!");
        Console.WriteLine(fi.FileName + ' ' + BitConverter.ToString(fi.FileHash));
        }
```

}", "*.*")
            .Select(
                f => new
                         {
                             FileName = f,
                             FileHash = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed()
                                                                .ComputeHash(new FileStream(f, 
                                                                                 FileMode.Open, 
                                                                                 FileAccess.Read))
                         })
            .ToList();

This loops through them all and looks for a match to the new one.

```
        foreach(var fi in allfiles){
        if(newfile == BitConverter.ToString(fi.FileHash))
            Console.WriteLine("Match!!!");
        Console.WriteLine(fi.FileName + ' ' + BitConverter.ToString(fi.FileHash));
        }
```

Ideally you would save this hash when the file is uploaded since this is very intense to recompute.

Comment: yes, this will prevent files which have not changed( this is, uploading the same file twice). I am still looking for a way to identify a file that has changed and to update it (this is uploading a file, changing it locally, uploading it again).

Comment: The only way I can think of is to have your uploader page pass along some unique ID of the file that they are overwriting.

Comment: looks like I can only prevent duplicates if the file has not changed. thanks for your examples.